# ListView smoothScrollToPosition working but setSelectionFromTop not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a list view and the requirement is to scroll the list pragmatically.

I am using this.

```
 // allClues.setSelection(clueIndex +1 );
 //allClues.setSelectionFromTop(clueIndex+1, rowWidth*noOfrows /2 + 50);

allClues.smoothScrollToPosition(clueIndex +1 );
allClues.invalidateViews();
```

It has a onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {



             ItemAdapter.selectedItem = position;

            view.setSelected(true);

            ((AbsListView) parent).invalidateViews();

            puzzle.setSelected(position);


          }
        }); 
    }
```

smoothScrolltoPosition is working fine, but the list ls long and its scrolled very frequently, therefor its not looking good.

when I am using setSelection to position the particular item at top and setSelectionFromTop
nothing is happining. Does these two methods require some pre condition, as smoothScrolltoPosition is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked -

```
        allClues.post(new Runnable() {            
                public void run() {
                    allClues.setSelection(ind);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

`setSelectionFromTop(..)` should work. As documentation says:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop%28int,%20int%29

public void setSelectionFromTop (int position, int y)

Parameters
position    Index (starting at 0) of the data item to be selected.
y   The distance from the top edge of the ListView (plus padding) that the item will be positioned.

So you probably are using it wrong. First parameter does not mean position where list should be scrolled.

Comment: I don't know whats going wrong here. setSelection(Index) and smoothScrollToPosition(Index) needs same arguments ? setSelectionFromTop (Index, 50) should put item at position Index 50 pixels down. but nothing is happening.

Comment: Since I have custom adapter, is any thing required in adapter. Can any thing im xml declaring ListView and rlayout of item in listView be responsible for this.